# Whats an explanation of PCA that is intuitive for someone in senior leadership who doesn't have a technical background?

Tags: prediction, pca

I've been pulled onto my first Data Science project at work. Classic problem of predicting sales based on web traffic data, etc. While I don't know about the specific techniques I will be using in my model, I think that PCA will probably be tried at some point, and if I use it successfully as a preprocessing step before I chug the data into some estimator, I'm thinking about how I might go about defending/explaining my work.

My question is, what is an intuitive explanation for PCA that doesn't rely heavily on the linear algebra that makes up the process? Perhaps an analogy that draws a parallel to something that any layman can readily understand?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Senior leadership won't care about such minutiae in my experience, but they might ask about your assumptions, and the model's weaknesses.

Comment: Checkout the answer on crossvalidation site of SE

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the main problems with PCA is the PC itself is a very abstract idea that doesn't map well to anything in the real world.

To someone non-technical, it lacks a reference point and it does not generate an insight that is readily actionable (i.e.,"Sales would improve if we change the colour of the font to blue")

As such, I'd suggest that you focus on the storytelling (e.g., the what?, so what?, and now what? framework, etc.), and only elaborate on what PCA is when asked.

For instance:
What: We build a prediction model based on web traffic to predict sales.
So what: The model shows that, if we do xyz xyz and increase xyz by xyz, the sales could potentially increase by xyz.
Now what:  We should validate such hypothesis by running a controlled test, blah blah blah. If it works, we should adopt the new process.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your explanation simple and brief. Maybe something like "PCA distils a dataset's features into as few attributes as possible; these attributes explain as much of the observed trend as possible while being as different from each other as possible". If you can do this using visual aids, even better.

As far as analogies go, maybe use an example of a motor accident. There are many predictors of an accident, but PCA may combine the majority of them to form 2 features - perhaps vehicle attributes and driver attributes. These are different but arguably are both highly predictive of a motor accident. [*I realise this is not technically how PCA works, but might help a **layman** understand*].

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are measuring the number of page visits as x and the time spent on the page as y, let’s say you measure it for each visitor/customer for a specific page.
If you create a scatter plot of x vs y, then you’ll get a Gaussian cloud of points in a 2-dimensional space. PCA can transform your data (cloud) from 2D to 1D, you can explain your data with a single variable rather than 2 variables. Once you decrease data dimensionality your problem (for example clustering or classifying the customers) would be easier to solve.